# When I try open a Adobe XD this message Appear to me adobe XD (error code: 5719)

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

When I try to open an Adobe XD this message Appears to me
adobe XD (error code: 5719)

[image]

Comment: Search on the internet for this error. It's a known problem on community.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below steps

. press WIN+R
. Type 'gpedit.msc' and press enter
. local group policy editor will open
.user configuration -> system (folder) -> click -> Download missing COM components ->Right click -> Edit -> change the 'Not Configured' to 'Disabled' and -> Apply

.After Restart your PC.